# malloc assertion in move_base

Tags: ros, navigation, c++, roscpp, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the following error running move_base against diamondback:
move_base: malloc.c:4630: _int_malloc: Assertion
`(unsigned long)(size) >= (unsigned long)(nb)' failed.
[move_base_node-1] process has died [pid 2403, exit code -6].
log files:

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9414/malloc-assertion-in-move_base/) by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1479 on 2011-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The cause of the error was that the nav launch file loaded a plugin (sbpl_recovery) that was not part of the released .deb packages, and had to be recompiled manually.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0